# ( Opencart v2.3 ) empty all shopping cart items in (minicart) in iphone

Tags: javascript, php, iphone, opencart, opencart2.3

> I would like to create a PHP file or a simple javascript code that
>   removes all the session cart items in the shopping cart.

what I have tried so far:

```
$json = array();
$this->cart->clear();
unset($this->session->data['vouchers']);
$json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_remove');
unset($this->session->data['shipping_method']);
unset($this->session->data['shipping_methods']);
unset($this->session->data['paymnet_method']);
unset($this->session->data['payment_methods']);
unset($this->session->data['reward']);
$json['total'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_items'), $this->cart->countProducts() + (isset($this->session->data['vouchers']) ? c$
$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
session_destroy();
```

I have tried the cart.remove(ID) and it doesn't work on (minicart) for some reason on iPhone.

There's no problem for Android phones only on iPhone

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48021355/how-to-add-a-button-to-clear-cart-in-opencart

Comment: Thank you, working now very helpful. +1